# C# WPF with SQLite Database Publishing in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, publishing

I have developed an application in C# using WPF. I want to publish the software to my website so users can download the installer and it will automatically update when I release a new version.

I am having a couple of problems with the publishing of the project.

First of all, the software is using an embedded SQLite Database. When I run the installer from the website, it downloads fine but does not include the database file that the software needs. How can I include the database file in to the installer.

The second problem is how to choose where the program installs to on the users PC. When I installed it I expected it would install to C:\Program Files\Company Name\Project Name but it doesn't put it there. How can I do this as well.

Thanks for any help you can provide with this.

Answer (score 0):

1. include your db file into project and restore db from it when application start
2. you are using clickonce, so you deal with sandbox application/ So you have 2 options - do not use clickonce (google for dday project for example or use windows installer) or use clickonce paths to found your files ([take a look](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformssetup/thread/6f2e2230-5a6e-458b-a924-fc86d2604e10/))